# Simple SQL Server database connection and reading a table on C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am new at this but I have a simple table in my SQL Server with one column `name` and 2 rows in it. I am trying to show up the names when pressing a button, I need to know how to connect the SQL Server database to the C# code and how to read from a specific table.

```
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connetionString;
            SqlConnection cnn;
            connetionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-REB699D\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBdemo";
            cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            cnn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Open  !");
            cnn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

But that didn't work, it crashes at the `cnn.open();` line of code.

Comment: `it crashes`  Always share the error message with us.

Comment: What @LarsTech says and then some guessing. You are trying a remote connection? Initially MSSQL Express only allows local access (TCP\IP is disabled).

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)'

Comment: Use the edit link under your question to include that information.

Comment: @MahmoudFarid is this a local DB in your computer?

Comment: Your connection string does not contain any information related to authentication like `User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;` or `Trusted_Connection=True;` or `Integrated Security=true;`. See [SQL Server connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Comment: @wisdomseeker yes this is local on my pc

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes and which one should i include ?,iam not using any credentials for my DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not using any credentials, its `windows authentication`.

Does adding `Integrated Security=True` to the connection string help?

Can you login to the DB without credentials on SSMS using `Windows authentication` option? If so, you don't need user credentials for connecting to DB. If you require a Username and password there,

1. you either need to include that in the connection string or
2. you need to enable `SQL Server and Windows Authentication` option under security tab to access the database without credentials

Comment: i tried integrated security and it worked ,thank u so much